# In Stack Overflow for teams, will there be a way to configure required reputation for privileges?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-for-teams

Actually, required reputation is set to 1 for every privilege. As we are using Teams in a school setup, there are a new load of students every year that we cannot trust blindly. These new students can edit/delete questions and this can be problematic because the owners needs to do extra moderation.

Are there plans to change things?

Comment: Your use case for Teams is to allow students to participate on the Teams site?

Comment: Yes, students can ask question specific to school projects, administration, lessons and other stuff. Other students answer the questions and popular topics becomes useful resources for new students.

Comment: Interesting. I posed the question since this seems like a counterintuitive use case for Teams; in a system with inherently no trust and a thin hierarchy, an Exchange system may be overkill. Since a private Team site assumes in large part that the hierarchy of the organization will deal with any gaps in the system, it implies more trust than you're equipped to handle right now. It's an interesting use case though; one I hadn't considered.

Comment: I quite like this use case. I'm not going to suggest my Uni department use it for various reasons, but it would be better than the current forum and comments system.

Answer (score -2):

If you can't trust them as new students how do you know that you can trust them later on when they built up some reputation? The problem you will have is there is a chance that they already know a bit about the system and they can slowly build up reputation from voting rings to do the damage they want to do later on.

In the end it all boils down to trust and a system has to be in place to handle violations of that trust.

If you do add a reputation system like is in place on non teams versions of sites you will just increase the work for everyone else anyway. That means people will need to take moderator activities just as they would on a normal site to deal with edit suggestions and clean up content from users who you don't trust to have the full privileges.

Possibly a better solution is to not give new students access to the system until you can give them proper instructions on the expectations and usage of the system so that they understand what to do and what will happen if they don't follow the rules. Even if the system of giving them accounts on the site is fully automated it shouldn't be hard to not have it happen until they finish an introductory class designed to help them learn about it. After all does it make sense to add more moderator work related to privileges because you want to limit work due to new users mistakes?

Comment: As you say, reputation won't prevent malicious students - there are rules  (students that tries to harm the system get temporarily banned) - but it will make it harder. New students with low rep must help others to grow their reputation.
The main issue resides in the big load of new students every year, there can be over 2000 new students coming the same month. This process is automatic and there is no way to "trust" a student because the only ones that meet students are other students.

Comment: I forgot to mention: the first thing a student gets when he join the school is an email address, it is his identity. Stack Overflow for teams only require an email address from the school.

Comment: @vxdcxw I still fail to see why you have to give every student automatic and immediate access to the teams site or why they would need it. Wouldn't it be much better to have an orientation where they get instruction/training/guidelines for the site and once that was completed they would gain access? I know that when I went back to school as a non traditional student there was still various things I had to do before I had access to all the tools.

Comment: candidates get an email address from the school as soon as they pass the first exam, then there is a 1 month event they must success before they get their student status. This email address is part of the core of the pedagogy. They cannot use it to send mail, but they can subscribe to many services. One solution would be to grant students who pass the final exam a new email address, but it would also break many other services and add complexity for moderators.

Comment: You are choosing to give them access to a service which they can cause some harm with (from needing to take action to undo what they may do) so Stack Exchange should take time away from other features to add back in something that by the vary nature of the service shouldn't be needed?

Comment: I'm not requesting this feature over another. I feel like this feature could help teams with a setup similar to our. I may be wrong, that's why I'm asking. If I don't explain my situation, who will know ?

Answer (score -3):

I expect privileges being dependent on badges and you being able to award badges based on a list of users you import would be a better model for you.